# Percona: What are the implications of changing repl.commit_order?

Tags: mysql, performance-tuning, percona

I'm currently doing some trials of Galera Cluster with Percona 5.6. I've progressed to testing a 2 node cluster on baremetal. With `repl.commit_order` set to 0 (off) the TPS performance as measured with sysbench is comparable to that of a standalone Percona instance.

When `repl.commit_order` is set to 3 (the default), TPS performance is around 10% compared to that of a standalone Percona instance.

Sysbench command in each instance is:

`sysbench --test=/usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/oltp.lua --oltp-table-size=5000000 --oltp-tables-count=1 --num-threads=32 --mysql-host=127.0.0.1 --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=**** --mysql-port=3306 --report-interval=1 --max-requests=0 --max-time=0 --mysql-db=sbtest run`

Firstly: What are the implications of the different commit_order modes?

Secondly: Can anyone suggest any other tweaks that will improve performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually turned out that other things could be done to improve cluster performance. These two links were useful resources:

http://openlife.cc/blogs/2011/august/running-sysbench-tests-against-galera-cluster

https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/12/07/linux-performance-tuning-tips-mysql/